# How to repaint a child window only once every frame using WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, direct3d

I'm using Direct3D and WinAPI to create windows and render 3D objects in the client area. I use the standard Windows message loop to invalidate the rectangle of the render window, and in the message handler of the render window, I perform a render call in Direct3D when processing the `WM_PAINT` message:

```
BOOL bRet; 
HWND mainWnd; // Main window
HWND renderWnd; // Child of mainWnd, takes up a portion of the client area 
                // to be used as a Direct3D render target

MSG msg = {};
while ((bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{
    if(bRet != -1)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        InvalidateRect(renderWnd, nullptr, false);
    }
} 

// ...

// Window procedure used by renderWnd
LRESULT renderWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        // ...
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            // Perform Direct3D rendering
            // ...
        }
        break;
        // ...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This setup seems to work correctly as long as my app only has one window, as `InvalidateRect` is called each frame and ensures that the client area needs to be redrawn, which in turn will result in a Direct3D draw call. It doesn't feel very elegant though, especially once I try to create multiple windows, as I'd have to invalidate their rectangles in that same piece of code, even if the features that the windows serve otherwise have nothing to do with each other (some of the windows might not even exist at any one time).

That said, my question is this: is it possible to have a window invalidate part of its client area *exactly once* each frame (assuming it's currently not minimized, etc.)? Maybe through the use of the message queue? Referring back to the above code segment: I'd want some way for `mainWnd` (perhaps in its own window procedure) to call `InvalidateRect` on `renderWnd` exactly once each frame.

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: small error in the code sample*

Comment: That's not once each frame. That's one each message. Which can be much more often than once a frame. You need to move the invalidate call to the point where you decide you want a new frame.

Comment: @RaymondChen Is there a specific message that can be used to determine what is the "next frame"?

Comment: The time for the "next frame" is up to you. Do you want a new frame every 16ms? Do you want a new frame when a particular event occurs? If nothing is happening, do you want another frame? You decide when the next frame is. Right now, you are invalidating after every message, which in particular means that you invalidate after every `WM_PAINT` message, so your window is always in an invalid state and is consuming 100% CPU repainting itself.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah I think you have the right idea. The example above is a somewhat stripped down version of the full app, the full thing essentially redraws and runs code whenever there are no messages to handle. I think my best bet is to just use a timer to invalidate and redraw the windows.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `PeekMessage` and drawing when there are no messages?

Comment: @Brandon I am, this was just a rushed sample I put together from the larger codebase I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of the comments on the original post, I figured out that the best option was to use the [Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers) provided by WinAPI to schedule a repaint of the render window at the required framerate. Going to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the 'standard' way to handle this is something more like this:

```
    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = {};
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            // Update your simulation/animation/etc. based on elapsed time
            //   -or-
            // multiple fixed time-steps.
            //
            // Then render one frame.
        }
    }

…

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
```

This model is a 'flat-out' rendering model where you will render as fast as the system can do it, limited by `Present` details like refresh rate and automatic throttling if you have 3 or more frames ready.

> You should take a look at [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) for some more details like implementing `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` / `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`.

The only time you'd implement `WM_PAINT` / `InvalidateRect` to render is if you are doing an editor or some 'mixed' UI and Direct3D application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, your line at the end happened upon the reason, I just didn't want to specify: I'm working on an editor, i.e mixed UI and Direct3D. The sample you provided is actually very close to how it currently operates, but it used to only have one window. Now I'm trying to expand it into having multiple windows with both UI and a render target.